# How to find out which public key to use to verify a JWT signature

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, apple-sign-in

I am trying to implement Sign In with Apple. I have an id_token which is a jwt token having `kid` value in the header. When I fetch the auth keys from [Apple](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys) I see that it returns more than 1 auth key. What is the efficient way of finding out which among these keys can be used validate the signature in the id_token as I do not want to loop through each public key. Looping through will result in unnecessary signature validation failures.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, because you already mention the `kid` that you get from the token header. And in the `JWK` set you get from Apple you just need to search for the matching `kid`. Of course you iterate through the list, but there should be know signature failures, because you would only try signature verification after you found the matching key. I laso don't understand your answer, it just merely says how to get the header, but you don't explain what you compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] parts = idToken.split("\\."); 
String headerJson = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[0]));
System.out.println(headerJson);
```

This will give the header and we can compare and then validate the signature.

Answer (score 0):

[Backend – Token verification](https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-3/)

1. get kid from identityToken.

> [[NSString alloc] initWithData:credential.identityToken
> encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

2. then match kid given by [apple server](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys)